# Sync projects folders in Webstorm

Tags: synchronization, phpstorm, webstorm

im using webstorm, and need to synchronize my project.  Im using git, so I need to sync two folders (below, in bold):

```
main
 -src ----> working on this folder
 -target
   -packaged-application  ---> need to reflect in this one.
```

All this folders have files. Not empty folders.

Basically I need to reflect the changes I made in "src" folder in my local apache server "packaged-application".

Any idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure WebStorm to deploy your application to a local folder (Settings - Build, execution, deployment - Deployment). See a tutorial on that for PhpStorm, it works the same way in WebStorm: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deploying+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm